# polymorphic HQL queries with conditions on concrete-class-specific properties; can it be done?

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism, hql

I have a hierarchy of classes mapped into hibernate that looks kind of like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Item { @ManyToOne Common common; ... }

@Entity
public class AbcItem extends Item { @ManyToOne Abc abc; ... }

@Entity
public class XyzItem extends Item { @ManyToOne Xyz xyz; ... }
```

That is, the several concrete classes share some associations, but each also have extra individual associations. (Since I’m using a single table, the columns a class doesn’t use are just NULL.)

What I’d like is to be able to query with HQL a list of items of mixed concrete class, *but* with a `where` clause that, depending on the specific class, puts conditions on the non-common properties. Something like “get all `Item`s i that have i.common = 7, but if they’re `AbcItem`s they must have abc = 5”.

It’s easy to query all items with `from Item`, and I know I can get the specific class with `.class`. But I can’t figure out a way of accessing the non-common properties or associations. Trying `from Item i where (i.class = AbcItem and i.abc = 5) or (i.class = XyzItem and i.xyz = 7)` causes Hibernate to complain that `Item` doesn’t have `abc` and `xyz`, which is true. Basically, it seems HQL has an `instanceof` but doesn’t have cast.

Am I missing something?

(Notes: I’m trying to do this in HQL — or even with Criteria queries if possible — rather than native SQL  to remain somewhat independent of the specific database engine. I know how to do it with native SQL, so don’t bother going there.

Also, I need to do this with *one* query. I know I can do individual queries for each class and merge the results. The trouble with that is that the application needs to paginate over the “merged” results, ordered by a common property. Doing it with separate queries would mean loading lots of unnecessary items, merge the lists, sort them, then discard most of them. The best algorithm I could figure out requires, for page N, loading the first N pages for each sub-query.)

Comment: The query you displayed would be OK if you had "and i.abc.id = 5" rather than "and i.abc = 5". Could you post the stack trace of the exception, because I've used such queries in the past (at least criteria queries) and they worked as is.

Comment: Hey, that actually works! Thank you, @jb-nizet! The resulting SQL query is too nasty for MySQL to optimize (see my answer to Pablo below, maybe you have a better idea), but this might come in handy later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "id" is the primary key:

```
from Item i
where (
   i.id in (select i2.id from AbcItem i2 where i2.abc = 5)
   or i.id in (select id2.id from XyzItem i2 where i2.xyz = 7)
   )
and ...
order by ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately the resulting SQL does a full scan over the `Item` table. In native SQL I UNIONed the sub-selects and joined the temporary table with `Item`; I can do the ORDER BY / LIMIT directly on the union result, which scans only on the page-sized temp table. HQL doesn’t seem to have anything like UNION.

Any idea of something similar done with HQL?